# Additivity of Heegaard genus under connected sum.

Tags: general-topology, low-dimensional-topology

Suppose $M_1, M_2$ are two closed three manifolds, $g(M_i)$ denote their Heegaard genus, is it true that $g(M_1\#M_2)=g(M_1)+g(M_2)?$ It is true that $g(M_1\#M_2)\leq g(M_1)+g(M_2),$ but I can't figure out how a sphere in $M_1\#M_2$ intersects the handlebodies of a splitting of $M_1\#M_2$, so I don't know if the inequality can be transformed into an equality. Appreciation for any comment!

Comment: See the top of page 4 of http://web.math.princeton.edu/facultypapers/Gabai/Heegaard.Survey.0.55.pdf which says it's due to Haken in its reference Ha3 .

Comment: Got it, thanks for your reply.